# Summarize documents by day of the week

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

For each student in a collection, I have an array of `absences`. I want to summarize the data by displaying the number of absences for each day of the week.

Given the following input:

```
{ 
    "_id" : 9373, 
    "absences" : [
        {
            "code" : "U", 
            "date" : ISODate("2021-01-17T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
            "full_day" : false, 
            "remote" : false, 
            "dayNumber" : 1, 
            "dayName" : "Sunday"
        }
    ]
}
{ 
    "_id" : 9406, 
    "absences" : [
        {
            "code" : "E", 
            "date" : ISODate("2020-12-09T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
            "full_day" : false, 
            "remote" : false, 
            "dayNumber" : 4, 
            "dayName" : "Wednesday"
        }, 
        {
            "code" : "U", 
            "date" : ISODate("2021-05-27T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
            "full_day" : false, 
            "remote" : false, 
            "dayNumber" : 5, 
            "dayName" : "Thursday"
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I achieve the following output:

```
[
  {
    "_id": 9373,
    "days": [
      {
        "dayNumber": 1,
        "dayName": "Sunday",
        "count": 1
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": 9406,
    "days": [
      {
        "dayNumber": 4,
        "dayName": "Wednesday",
        "count": 1
      },
      {
        "dayNumber": 5,
        "dayName": "Thursday",
        "count": 1
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I've pushed all the required fields to this stage of the pipeline. I'm just not clear how to roll up the data in the nested `absences` array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `$unwind` deconstruct `absences` array
- `$group` by `_id` and `dayNumber`, and get count of grouped documents
- `$group` by `_id` and reconstruct `days` array

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $unwind: "$absences" },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        _id: "$_id",
        dayNumber: "$absences.dayNumber"
      },
      dayName: { $first: "$absences.dayName" },
      count: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id._id",
      days: {
        $push: {
          dayName: "$dayName",
          dayNumber: "$_id.dayNumber",
          count: "$count"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/6ff8BSWBKZb)

Comment: Thank you so much. One final tweak I want to make is sorting the results by the day number. Adding `{ "$sort" : {  "_id" : 1,  "days.dayNumber" : 1.0  } }` doesn't do the trick. Any thoughts?

Comment: for internal days array sorting put sort before the last $group stage and root level documents sorting put at the last stage. see [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/6rnNo9XmEL8)